# Viewing document file contents within an ASP .NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, document

I have an ASP .NET web page which lists e-mail attachments. These attachments are your typical .docx, .pdf, .jpg, .tiff etc formats.

I'm looking for a solution (perhaps a component?) that will allow me to view the contents of these attachments in a scrollable panel for review by the user.

We have decided against the option of downloading the file and viewing it locally - so that's not an option.

Any ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: Each of ".docx, .pdf, .jpg, .tiff etc formats" has a different solution... your question is way too too broad.

Comment: Of course, previewing images is trivial, just use a regular img tag and have the browser just display the images that way.  For viewing .docx and .pdf files without having the client download the actual files, I can recommend the ABCPdf component from WebSuperGoo.

Comment: @spender Accusoft's Prizm Content Connect software does about 300 file formats, using Flash or HTML5 rendering. It'sexpensive though, understandably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, Accusoft's Prizm Content Connect software has an HTML5 viewer for over 300 different formats, but has a heavy price tag on it.

Considering the priority of file formats I need to support, I settled on the solutions below:

PDF - Free; [pdfobject](http://pdfobject.com/) provides a lightweight javascript option that embeds into the page.

Image Formats - Free; A simple native image control can be used.

Docx/Doc - License; [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) provides a component to build and view Word documents in WinForms and ASP .NET